# How can I receive WSOL on Solana devnet?

Tags: solana

Curious to know how can I get wsol on Solana devnet. Coming from a EVM background this process seems cumbersome! Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

If you want WSOL, you'll need to airdrop SOL and then wrap it. To airdrop you can run:

```
$ solana --url devnet airdrop 1
```

Note that there are pretty strict rate limits on the airdrop!

After that, you can wrap with

```
$ spl-token --url devnet wrap 0.5
```